# Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still new to Unity and I'm following a tutorial to try to learn Unity but I got stuck at a part. I'm making a space invaders game and I've instantiated the enemies but when I say 'this' to refer to the enemies, I get many errors saying 'this' doesn't exist in the current context.

Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;




public class Invaders : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Invader[] prefabs;
    
    public int rows = 4;

    public int columns = 7;

    public float speed = 0.5f;

    public int ammountKilled { get; private set; }
    
    public int totalInvaders = this.rows * this.columns;

    public float percentKilled = (float)this.ammountKilled / (float)this.totalInvaders;


    private Vector3 _direction = Vector2.right;

    private void Awake() {
        for (int row = 0; row < this.rows; row++)
        {
            float width = 1.0f * (this.columns - 1);
            float height = -0.5f * (this.rows - 1);
            Vector2 centering = new Vector2(-width / 2, -height / 2);
            Vector3 rowPosition = new Vector3(centering.x, centering.y + (row * 1.0f), 0.0f);

            for (int col = 0; col < this.columns; col++)
            {
                Invader invader = Instantiate(this.prefabs[row], this.transform);
                invader.killed += InvaderKilled;
                Vector3 position = rowPosition;
                position.x += col * 1.0f;
                invader.transform.position = position;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        this.transform.position += _direction * this.speed.Evaluate(this.percentKilled) * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 leftEdge = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero);
        Vector3 rightEdge = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.right);

        foreach (Transform invader in this.transform){
            if (!invader.gameObject.activeInHierarchy) {
                continue;
            }

            if(_direction == Vector3.right && invader.position.x > rightEdge.x) {
                AdvanceRow();
            }   else if (_direction == Vector3.left && invader.position.x < (leftEdge.x)){
                AdvanceRow();
            }
        }
    }

    private void AdvanceRow()
    {
        _direction.x *= -1.0f;

        Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
        position.y -= 1.0f;
        this.transform.position = position;
    }

    private void  InvaderKilled(){

    }

}
```

There might be a few inconsistencies in there like I typed amount a ton of different ways on accident (amound, amount ammount). I've tried to fix them all but I'm sure I missed some.

Here's the errors:

> [14:41:21) Assets/Scripts/Invaders.cs(18,32): error CS0027: Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context
> 1 114:41:211 Assets/Scripts/Invaders.cs(18,44): error CSO027: Keyword 'this'"is not available in the current context
> [14:41:21) Assets/Scripts/Invaders.os(20,41): error CS0027: Keyword "this' is not available in the current context
> [14:41:211 Assets/Scripts/Invaders.os(20,69): error CS0027: Keyword this' is not available in the current context
> [14:41:21] Assets/Scripts/Invaders.c(46,60): error CS1061: 'float' does not contain a definition for 'Evaluate' and no accessible extension method 'Evaluate' accepting a first argument of type 'float' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You may want to make totalInvaders and percentKilled get-only properties, to have them always give the current value. Now you are initializing their values once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're receiving this error because you're using the `this` keyword outside of a property, function or constructor.

You should move the assignments of `totalInvader` and `percentKilled` inside of the `Awake` method like so:

```
public int totalInvaders;

public float percentKilled;

...

private void Awake() 
{
    totalInvaders = this.rows * this.columns;
    percentKilled = (float)this.ammountKilled / (float)this.totalInvaders;
    
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: You can just skip `this` in this context. It's really only useful when distinguishing between method parameters and fields.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `this` keyword is not allowed in certain contexts, such as field or property initializers.

To work around this you can move the initialization of the `totalInvaders` and `percentKilled` variables inside the Awake method.

Comment: `private bool WasQuickToDownvote { get; set; } = this.playerData;`

Answer (score 0):

`this` is only valid inside a method body, and it really isn't needed at all unless there's a conflict of naming that requires more resolution. You can simply assign the field without using `this`:

```
public int TotalInvaders = rows * columns;
```

Note that you've made `totalInvaders` a public field, which means it can be edited from anyone with a reference to the class. If you mean for it to be a read-only property, you can use the following `=>` syntax instead (and then keep the `this` references):

```
public int TotalInvaders => this.rows * this.columns;
```

The syntax above is a shortcut for providing a single `get` accessor to the property, which could also be written:

```
public int TotalInvaders { get { return this.rows * this.columns; } }
```